# php session_destroy() setcookie time()

Tags: php, session-cookies

In the [example on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) to use `session_destroy()`, it specifies to delete a cookie:

```
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000, $params["path"], $params["domain"], $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]);
}
```

Should the 42000 seconds be changed? What value should one use? I don't recall setting any cookies in my session, but I believe `php.ini` has it setup to use cookies by default.

Answer (score 5):

PHP set the cookie by default. When you create a *session* in PHP, PHP will generate a corresponding session ID and pass that back and forth on requests in the HTTP headers. This is how the server knows what session data to associate with a particular user.

You do not need to change the `42000`. The point of this number is to set the cookie to expire to a time long passed. By doing so, the browser will remove the corresponding cookie, removing the reference to the stored session data on the server, thereby "clearing" the session.

The session data on the server will be removed at a later time by the PHP garbage collector as specified by the time given in your `php.ini` configuration file.

Below is a reference to the default session configuration settings used when PHP is installed.

**Reference:** [Session Configuration Settings](http://www.php.net//manual/en/session.configuration.php)

Comment: Doesn't `session_destroy()` remove the session data in the first place?

Comment: @sjagr I don't believe so. According to the [documentation](http://us2.php.net//manual/en/function.session-destroy.php): _"**session_destroy()** destroys all of the data associated with the current session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie. To use the session variables again, session_start() has to be called."_ I've seen this occur before where session data is recovered by calling `session_start()` again. I think the garbage collector has to run to completely remove the temporary file.

Comment: Can't the session variable references be removed with `$_SESSION = array();` though, as per the docs? Ultimately nothing is ever deleted for certain (memory still needs to be garbage collected and disk clusters have to be rewritten), but the example in the docs looks pretty complete.

Comment: @sjagr That's correct. The example they provide is excellent. It sounded like the OP was asking why the example was so thorough (in terms of clearing cookies and such) rather than just calling `session_destroy();`. The OP said he/she didn't set any cookies and wasn't quite clear why they needed to be removed. I was just explaining that this is all part of how PHP works out of the box and how the cookie provides a reference to the data. In order to truly break the session you have to break the corresponding reference. This is just an explanation of what's happening.